# how to make the header on a r markdown generated pdf take the whole page width?

Tags: r, pdf, header, latex, r-markdown

I am trying to create a pdf document that needs to use certain margins, which i define on the geometry. Then, i need to add an image as the header of the first page, but i need that image to take the whole width of the page (not to have white margins on the left and right). Is there a way to achieve that? Here is what i have so far, I tried changing width to width=paperwidth, but that didn't work:

```
---
title: ""
author: ""
date: ''

geometry: left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,twoside

header-includes:
  - "\\usepackage[spanish]{babel}"
  - "\\usepackage{fancyhdr}"
  - "\\usepackage{graphicx}"
  - "\\pagestyle{fancy}"
  - "\\fancyhf{}"
  - "\\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{"
  - "\\fancyhf{}"
  - "\\fancyhead[C]{\\includegraphics[width=15cm]{I:/markdown pdf/encabezado2.png}}"
  - "}"
  - "\\renewcommand{\\headrulewidth}{0pt}"
  - "\\setlength{\\headheight}{68.0658pt}"
  - "\\addtolength{\\topmargin}{-58.0658pt}"
  - "\\setlength{\\headsep}{0.5cm}"
  - "\\fancyfoot[C]{\\includegraphics[width=15cm]{I:/markdown pdf/pie de pagina.png}}"
  - "\\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\\thepage}"
  - "\\pagenumbering{gobble}"
  - "\\setcounter{page}{1}"
  - "\\usepackage[labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}"

output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
  html_document:
    highlight: tango
    theme: cerulean
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
mainfont: Calibri
papersize: a4
always_allow_html: true
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: "1.5"

---

\thispagestyle{firstpage}
```